# Как правильно хранить числа с плавающей точкой в базе данных SQLite3

Tags: python, математика, sqlite3, числа

пишу небольшое скрипт на Python к которому подкручена база данных SQLite3

Я записываю в базу данных числа с плавающей точкой ( или без неё ), чтобы потом вывести сумму этих чисел, но проблема в том что если в базе данных если число с двумя знаками после точки ( например: 14.55 ), то результат будет примерно вот таким: из списка с числами [55, 14.55, 21.9, 27, 27, 11.95, 45] выйдет вот такое число - 202.39999999999998. Если чисел с двумя знаками после точки не будет, всё будет нормально.

Числа в базу данных я записываю в виде float, а в базе данных я их храню real ( пробовал с numeric, но результат такой же )

Вопрос: как правильно складывать и хранить такие числа? Может лучше использовать другую базу данных?

Comment: скорее вам нужно использовать другую компьютерную архитектуру, которая хранит числа с плавающей запятой правильно. Но для начала его нужно изобрести.

Comment: Насколько я понял в `SQLite` по факту `Numeric` становится либо `Integer`, либо `Real`. Чтобы хранить точные значения нужна БД, поддерживающая "настоящий" тип `decimal` (он же `numeric`). И в питоне тоже нужно использовать `Decimal`. Ну либо просто округляйте потом при выводе числа до какого-то знака, думаю, для ваших целей этого будет достаточно.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Здесь проблема не в базе данных, вы же при обычном сложении в интерпретаторе тот же результат получите

```py
sum([55, 14.55, 21.9, 27, 27, 11.95, 45])
```

```
202.39999999999998
```

Так что в базе вы можете хранить их хоть даже в виде строки, а потом преобразовывать во `float`.

Здесь получается такое число скорее из-за особенностей [**проблемы чисел с плавающей точкой**](https://docs-python.ru/tutorial/operatsii-chislami-python/problemy-chisel-plavajuschej-zapjatoj/). Результат получается верный.

Если вам нужно просто вывести с точностью до 2 знаков после запятой, то воспользуйтесь форматированием строки:

```py
f'{числовое_значение:.кол-во_знаковf}'
```

```py
print(f'{sum([55, 14.55, 21.9, 27, 27, 11.95, 45]):.2f}')
```

```py
'202.40'
```

Если вам нужно именно конкретное значение в виде числа для дальнейшей работы, то можете также обрезать его вернув обратно во `float` уже отформатированное значение

```py
a = float(f'{202.39999999999998:.2f}')
```

```py
202.4
```

Comment: Спасибо вам большое за помощь

Comment: я не совсем понял sqlite поддерживает DECIMAL ? К примеру нужно сохрнять данные с точностью до 8 знаков (биржевые данные), то какой формат стоит выбирать для храния и работы с данными ?